# systemd Force Service to Complete Before Proceeding in CentOS 7.1

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a service that needs to complete before I can let Linux start up continue. I'd rather not have to specify each service and target in a `Before=` statement in my `.service` files. In SysVInit, I just specified the start number I wanted with chkconfig.

I have tried defining a `foo.target` and a `foo.service` and set it with `require=` and `after=` for `network.target` (I need networking) as well as `before=multi-user.target`. This doesn't seem to be working. I have set up the `foo.target.wants` directory to have a symlink to `foo.service`.

I have tried turning on debug in `system.conf`, to see what's wrong and had disastrous results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got everything working the way I wanted. It's not pretty, but...

I changed the `systemd` default to a special target that wants what services are needed and runs my script at the end. At the end of my script, `systemctl isolate multi-user` is issued. I've verified that this works as desired.